# Nhibernate 3.0 with FluentNHibernate 1.2

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, spring.net

I'm working on a project which currently uses NHibernate 2.1.2, FluentNHibernate 1.1 and Spring.Net 1.3.1

I am trying to upgrade to using NHibernate 3.

The problem I am having is Spring.Net 1.3.1 supports NHibernate 3.0 and FluentNHibernate 1.2 seems to only support NHibernate 3.1

Is there a way to get FluentNHibernate 1.2 working with NHibernate 3.0?

I need to be using stable release versions of each.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring 1.3.2 releases friday 15th of April [(see their tracker)](https://jira.springsource.org/secure/BrowseProject.jspa?id=10020) and it ships with NHibernate 3.1. This might solve your issue.

Comment: I reckon it can wait until Friday! Should have checked this myself. Thanks!